# Passing Multiple Value For PHP API Function

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I am new in PHP and working to modify one API. Its built with Laravel Framework. I have API function like below in my controller.

```php
public function DeleteOneMail(Request $request)
{
    $uid = $request->uid;

    if (\Request::is('api/*')) {
        if ($request->has('key')) {
            if (in_array($request->input('key'), explode(',', env('API_KEY')))) {
                if ($uid == '') {
                    return response()->make('Please Enter UID', 401);
                } else {
                    $client = Client::account('default');
                    $client->connect();
                    $inbox = $client->getFolder('INBOX');
                    $message = $inbox->getMessage($uid);
                    if ($message) {
                        return response(['success' => 1], 200);
                    } else {
                        return response(['success' => 0, 'message' => 'No Data Found'], 200); 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return response()->make('Unauthorized Access. Please enter correct API Key', 401);
            }
        } else {
            return response()->make('Unauthorized Access. Please enter correct API Key', 401);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling API like below

```
https://example.com/api/delete-one-mail?key=2221212&uid=214
```

Its working fine without any issue. Now I want pass multiple uid with request and so I can process that uid one by one with my api function. I am not getting idea how I can pass arrary and process it. Let me know if any expert can help me for solve my puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest if you're willing to remove multiple uid's, pass them via post body as an array, rather than through get. Will be much cleaner solution.

Comment: i agree with Ed T. but if you really want in GET request, you can use a list like `&uid=214,215,217`

Comment: Also, in the part where you return "No Data Found", you're also sending 200 status code, that's a bit incorrect. Following RESTful principles, you should return 404 or 400, can't remember which one exactly suits the case.

Comment: @EdT. that would be 400. 404 is for when there's no matching route found. 400 would be more suitable if a route was found, but there is no data found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can pass an array like this

```
https://example.com/api/delete-one-mail?key=2221212&uid[]=214&uid[]=111&uid[]=222
```

`$request->uid` should be an array but you can make sure (if anyone use the old url with ony one uid) by doing

```
$uids = Arr::wrap($request->uid);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send an array by GET request just use []

```
https://example.com/api/delete-one-mail?key=2221212&uid[]=1&uid[]=2
```

In your controller you will get an array

```
$uid = $request->uid;
dd($uid);
```

As a result you will get

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: I do not understood what is dd($uid); here. Thanks!

Comment: dd() is laravel helper function. It means Dump and Die, try and you'll see the best output ever)